# Karn, the Great Creator - what defines a 'card from outside the game' in sealed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, sealed-deck

In the upcoming set 'War of the Spark' there is the Planeswalker [Karn, the Great Creator](http://mythicspoiler.com/war/cards/karnthegreatcreator.html). His -2 ability reads as:

> -2: You may choose an artifact card you own from outside the game or in exile, reveal that card and add it to your hand

Now my question is, in a sealed tournament, like the Prerelease, is a player allowed to also choose cards from outside his sealed cardpool, or only out of the cards therein. Does anyone know any rulings on stuff like that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the same wording as used on e.g. the Wish cycle from Judgment. An example is [Golden Wish](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGolden%20Wish%5d). Its rulings at the bottom say

> 10/1/2009     In a sanctioned event, a card that’s “outside the game” is one that’s in your sideboard. In an unsanctioned event, you may choose any card from your collection.

So in a Sealed event, you're limited to your sideboard, which according to the [Tournament Rules](https://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_21jan19_en.pdf) are the 'rest' of the opened cards you're not using in your deck. (Of course, exiled cards can be chosen as well.)

> 7.1 Deck Construction Restrictions
>
> Limited decks must contain a minimum of forty cards. There is no maximum deck size. Any drafted or opened cards not used in a player’s Limited deck function as their sideboard.

Comment: I would suggest closing the loop with this quote from the Magic Tournament Rules section 7.1: "Any drafted or opened cards not used in a player’s Limited deck function as their sideboard."

Comment: Also for a direct rule quote in addition to/instead of the card ruling, the end of section 3.15 of the tournament rules says "Certain cards refer to 'a (card or cards) from outside the game.' In tournament play, these are cards in that player’s sideboard."